# How to show dynamic variables in a push notification in Android (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification

My application is counting some numbers and I want to show that number in the push notification.

I have 2 questions; how do I pass this number as a parameter to my notification_view.xml and how do I update that number when changed? Do I need to update the current notification using the same notification channel?

I didn't put any code example because I couldn't even find something to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to [update notification](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/notify-user/managing.html),for example:

```
mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated
int notifyID = 1;
mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("New Message")
    .setContentText("You've received new messages.")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify_status)
numMessages = 0;
// Start of a loop that processes data and then notifies the user
...
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentText(currentText)
        .setNumber(++numMessages);
    // Because the ID remains unchanged, the existing notification is
    // updated.
    mNotificationManager.notify(
            notifyID,
            mNotifyBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Got it, thank you. But this doesn't answer the first question. I am showing some numbers inside my `notification_view.xml`. So the content of the notification comes from this file, meaning that I am not doing `setContentTitle` or `setContentText`. But instead I set the content like this: `.setContent(RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.notification_view))` How do I update a UI element inside this `notification_view.xml` from my let's say `MainActivity.kt`?

Comment: declare    `val mRemoteViews = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.notification_view)`  ,and then   `.setContent(mRemoteViews)`  ,you can update UI element with `mRemoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.number, "12"); `,and don't forget to call `mNotificationManager.notify( notifyID, mNotifyBuilder.build());`